# caption setting, bolded figure and table, and single spacing without caption package

Tags: floats, formatting, captions, bold

These limitations and difficulties I face because I couldn't use `caption` package. If I add `\usepackage{caption}`, I couldn't preview my document.. I'm using BaKoMa TeX. There are a lot of bugs which is beyond repair for this moment. :-(

1. I need to have the word `Figure` in the `figure` environment caption to be **bold**. (same goes for `table`)
2. If possible I want the caption length is equal to table's width and it is in single spacing. The whole document is in double spacing. For example

[image]

Here is the LaTeX code:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{booktabs,xcolor,amssymb} %% also needed
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[H]\label{comparisonfourierandnonfourier1}\caption{Comparison between Fourier and Non-Fourier heat conduction equation (HCE).}\centering
\begin{tabular}{l c c}
\toprule
\textbf{\textcolor{blue}{Item}} & \textbf{\textcolor{blue}{Fourier HCE}} &    
\textbf{\textcolor{blue}{non-Fourier HCE}}\\
\midrule
1) conservation energy & same & same \\ 
2) heat flux equation & $q=-k\triangledown T$ & $\tau\displaystyle\frac{\partial q}   
{\partial t}+q=-k\frac{\partial T}{\partial r}$ \\ 
3) equation form & parabolic  & hyperbolic \\ 
4) heat propagation & infinite  & finite \\ 
5) temperature gradient & moderate  & extreme \\ 
\bottomrule\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Is there any other way to do this given that the limitation I face... by only using the
`graphicx` package? Maybe some `\renewcommand` perhaps... I do appreciate for your advice.

Answer (score 5):

I've taken your MWE and made the following main changes:

- I inserted the full definition of the internal LaTeX macro `\@makecaption` (from report.cls) and changed its settings so that the float's name (Figure or Table) and number are set in bold. (Aside: This partial redefinition of the macro `\@makecaption` could be accomplished more elegantly, in general, by loading the `etoolbox` package and invoking the `\patchcmd` macro. However, since your TeX distribution appears to be so old that the `caption` package won't even work correctly, I have a hunch that the `etoolbox` package won't be available either...)
- I changed the table environment from `tabular` to `tabular*` and provided further code so that the table automatically occupies a width of `\textwidth` (by adding the unwieldy-looking item `@{\extracolsep{\fill}}`).
- You mention separately that your document is set double-spaced but that you want the caption's text (if it occupies more than 1 line) to be single-spaced. Your MWE doesn't actually show *how* you achieve double-spacing, so I've tried to mimic that by loading the `setspace` package and invoking `\doublespacing`. This approach has an important advantage: all items such as footnotes and floats will automatically be single-spaced regardless of the spacing in the "main" body of the document.

An additional comment: Always place the `\label` command *after* the float's `\caption` command. Otherwise, your cross-references won't be correct.

[image]

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{booktabs,xcolor,amssymb} %% also needed
\usepackage{setspace}
\doublespacing
\makeatletter
% need to modify definition of \@makecaption macro
% (found in report.cls)
\long\def\@makecaption#1#2{%
  \vskip\abovecaptionskip
  \sbox\@tempboxa{\textbf{#1}: #2}% % change "#1" to "\textbf{#1}"
  \ifdim \wd\@tempboxa >\hsize
    \textbf{#1}: #2\par             % change "#1" to "\textbf{#1}"
  \else
    \global \@minipagefalse
    \hb@xt@\hsize{\hfil\box\@tempboxa\hfil}%
  \fi
  \vskip\belowcaptionskip}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\caption{Comparison between Fourier and Non-Fourier heat conduction equation (HCE).}
\label{comparisonfourierandnonfourier1}
%\centering % no longer needed
\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{}l@{\extracolsep{\fill}} c c@{}}
\toprule
\textbf{\textcolor{blue}{Item}} & 
\textbf{\textcolor{blue}{Fourier HCE}} &    
\textbf{\textcolor{blue}{non-Fourier HCE}}\\
\midrule
1) conservation energy & same      & same \\ 
2) heat flux equation  & $q=-k\triangledown T$ & 
   $\tau\displaystyle\frac{\partial q}   
   {\partial t}+q=-k\frac{\partial T}{\partial r}$ \\[1.5ex]
3) equation form       & parabolic & hyperbolic \\ 
4) heat propagation    & infinite  & finite \\ 
5) temperature gradient& moderate  & extreme \\ 
\bottomrule
\end{tabular*}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: thank you mico, it works good after adding your modification to my preamble. but i do only want the caption to be in single line and not the table content... which part should i check to make the table's content to be double spacing back? thank you for your advise.

Comment: @azlanaznam - Thanks for letting me know that the suggestions work for you. If you want to maintain your previous method for achieving double-spaced text (which you haven't given us any details about so far), you are obviously free to do so. :-) Just don't load the `setspace` package in that case.

Comment: after I uncomment 'setspace' package, the document returns back to double spacing, unfortunately the caption aren't as equal as the table's width.                                                                                  my apology for not mentioning how I set my document as double spacing. here is the command '\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{2}'

Comment: @azlanaznam: When you say that "the caption[s] aren't as [wide] as the table" -- just *how* wide are they? Are they wider (e.g., as wide as the text block), or are they less wide? Relatedly, did you make the switch from `tabular` to `tabular*` environments? (The `tabular*` environments allows you to specify a set width.)

Comment: after change `tabular` to `tabular*`, problem solved, no problem with caption width, it fit to the table width. but the caption still in double spacing and Figure are not in bold (All Table words are OK, in bold).

Comment: @azlanaznam - the double-spacing of the captions is a direct consequence of your choice to set `\baselinestretch` to 2. (I continue to think that's a terrible setting. Get rid of it, load the `setspace` package instead, and execute `\doublespace`.) Please consider posting a new question to explain your remaining issues.